# how to use MSGBOX YES NO

Tags: vb.net

i have the right codes for this. when i press yes the command will execute but when i press the NO the sub doesnt exit it still executes the command.. can someone help me?? im a newbee in vb programing.. (sorry for the english)

heres the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim payed As Integer
        Dim balance As Integer
        Dim paying As Integer
        Dim d As Integer
        Dim c As Integer
        Try

            Dim ans As Integer
            If TextBox7.Text = "" Or 0 Then

                MsgBox("please enter amount", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Else
                If TextBox6.Text = 0 Then

                    MsgBox("the student is fully payed", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Else
                    ans = MsgBox(" are you want to upadate the students payment? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "confirm ")
                    If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then


                        payed = Val(TextBox5.Text)
                        balance = Val(TextBox6.Text)
                        paying = Val(TextBox7.Text)
                        d = payed + paying
                        c = balance - paying
                        TextBox5.Text = d
                        TextBox6.Text = c

                        Dim SqlQuery = "UPDATE sample SET [Payed Amount] ='" & TextBox5.Text & "',Balance ='" & TextBox6.Text & "' WHERE ID = " & a & " ; "
                        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
                        With sqlcommand
                            .CommandText = SqlQuery
                            .Connection = conn
                            .ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End With
                        MsgBox("student payment succesfully updated")
                        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CASHREG, AudioPlayMode.Background)
                        If TextBox6.Text = 0 Then
                            MsgBox("the student is now fully paid", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                            TextBox7.Text = ""
                        Else

                            MsgBox("students current balance is " & Convert.ToString(TextBox6.Text))
                            LoadListView()
                            TextBox7.Text = ""
                        End If
                    Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

This is part of your code:

```
ans = MsgBox(" are you want to upadate the students payment? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "confirm ")
If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
```

You are assigning the result of the message box call to `ans`, but then you aren't actually *testing* the value of `ans`. When you say

```
If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
```

this will *always be true*, because `MsgBoxResult.Yes` is a constant value which will always come out as `True`. You actually want this test to be

```
If ans = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
```

---

I'm slightly surprised that what you have compiles, although VB.NET isn't my strong point. I would suggest you always use `Option Strict` in your code, which I believe would show this up as a problem at compile time.